# UILabel becomes null after facebook login (UILabel dosen't update)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on adding facebook SSO and the SDK to my project. All of my main facebook code is in my `AppDelegate.m` and `AppDelegate.h`.
In my view controller `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:@selector(callLogin)];` is called when I press a button.
The callLogin method in my `AppDelegate.m` looks like this:

```
- (void)callLogin{

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"XXXXX" andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
    }
}
```

Then in my `- (void)fbDidLogin` method I call the method `setInfo` which is located in my viewcontroller.

```
//this method is located in AppDelegate.m
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSLog(@"FACEBOOK DID LOGIN");
ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[vc setInfo]; 
}
```

Finally, here is my `-(void)setInfo` code which is located in `ViewController.m`

```
-(void)setInfo{
infoL.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Connected to Facebook!"];
NSLog(@"%@",infoL);
//NSLog returns null
}
```

From setInfo I am unable to change the label and NSLog returns that `infoL` is null. I can update the label through methods like ViewDidLoad, but not setInfo.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Is the `UILabel` that you're updating in your root view controller? If so, you'll need to call `setInfo` with your root view controller rather than creating a new instance of the view controller.

Comment: I only create an instance of viewcontroller so I can call the `setInfo` method using `AppDelegate.m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view controller won't get updated because you just created some random instance of the class that is not on your navigation stack. I suppose you could call

```
 [ self.viewController setInfo ]
```

assuming that is the property name for the vc you pushed on the stack in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions although this wouldn't be considered great design. Id factor Facebook delegate stuff out out app delegate, create a Facebook controller singleton class that your view controller can feed off

Answer (score 0):

I assume that infoL represents a UILabel.  Do you create this label in code or is an outlet that is created automatically?

If you create infoL in code, where is it allocated/initted?  Is it non-nil at any time before your setInfo method runs?

Comment: Control-clicked the UILabel from interfacebuilder and dragged to code so it was created automatically.